# 属性エラー赤文字　理由がわからないです、ご指導お願いします。

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf=8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1A9BA"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLabelInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/tv_msg"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
</LinearLayou>
```

テキスト通りにはやっていたとおもうのです。。。
スペル間違い以外の属性エラーがという感じです。

テキストサイトのサンプルコードもアンドロイドスタジオで開いてみても同じところ赤文字です。。

ぐぐっても？？です。詳しい方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そのまま記載するとHTMLタグに埋もれて見えなくなります。コードを選択して`{}`ボタンを押すとコードハイライトされますので活用ください。

Comment: どの属性がエラーになったのか追記可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

```
</LinearLayou>
```

の最後にtが抜けてる気がします。

正しくは

```
</LinearLayout>
```

じゃないでしょうか？

Comment: すいませんtはここでの記入で抜けてました。。

Comment: また、Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality...が電球マークです。BasicFunctionality？のなにを見直していけばよろしいでしょうか？？再度よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーメッセージが出力されている状態でのスクリーンショットをアップロードすることはできますか？